# How to use a local SOCKS server as a gateway?

Tags: routing, iptables, gateway, socks

I'm running a SOCKS proxy server (on an Ubuntu machine) which is used to bypass internet censorship. I'd like the devices in the same network (such as TVs etc), which don't support SOCKS, to use this proxy.

Given that these devices have very basic network settings (i.e. you can only set an IP and gateway), the only solution I can think of is to use the Ubuntu machine as a gateway and route all the traffic through it. The question is how do I do this (perhaps using iptables) assuming that the Ubuntu machine is already running a DHCP server.

I'm looking for the most straightforward solution, and would highly prefer to use existing software, but don't mind writing some code in Java or Python if necessary.

Comment: Could you update the question to make it clear whether you are willing to develop some of the code needed to achieve this on your own? Or if you are only looking for solutions which can be achieved using existing software?

Comment: if you were open to a Windows solution, you can use a product like [WinGate](http://www.wingate.com) to intercept the connections from the unsupported devices, and pipe them through a SOCKS server.  Disclaimer, I work for Qbik who are the authors of WinGate.  Let me know and I can make this an answer if you're interested.

Comment: @adrien could you elabrote?

Comment: Max - WinGate can act as a default gateway for a client computer, intercept TCP connections on any defined ports and pipe it via a proxy that will then make a SOCKS connection to the original destination via a SOCKS server.